# Issue getting num_rows with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got this code:

```
$query  = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "' . $user . '" AND password = MD5("' . $pass . '") LIMIT 1';  
echo $query;
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
echo "<br>Here: " . $result->num_rows;
```

Using the output from `$query` I put it into phpmyadmin and it returns 1 row but when trying to get the number of rows using `num_rows` it doesn't return anything at all - not even 0;

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you receive any errors? Do you have error reporting on?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

> Returns FALSE on failure.

Have you established a connectection to your DB?

Comment: Good point on the connection. I would go further in asking if the $mysqli object is available within the scope of the code your in right now.

Comment: My mistake. Turns out I was connecting to the wrong database. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the SQL query is messed up. As far as I know there is no MD5 function built into MySQL nor the SQL standard. Therefore if it does exist then it is probably proprietary to the particular DB.

That said you can use PHP to check it. Try this to see what is going on.

```
$encrypted_pass = md5($pass);
$query  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$encrypted_pass' LIMIT 1";  
echo $query;
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result !== FALSE) {
  echo "<br>Here: " . $result->num_rows;
}
else {
  echo "Something is broken.";
}
```

Ref:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php